# Table x has no column y even after app has been reset

Tags: python, django, model

I ran "python manage.py reset appname" and then "python manage.py syncdb" because I was getting an error of:

> "DatabaseError: table x has no column named y".

While one of the new columns I added in the new view (created_on) worked, I'm still having trouble with the "rating" column.  Any advice?

```
class Review(models.Model):
    review = models.CharField('Review', max_length = 2000)
    date = models.DateField('date')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    user = models.CharField('Username', max_length =  200)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.review
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use commands:

```
python manage.py sqlclear appname
python manage.py syncdb
```

or better use [south](http://south.aeracode.org/)